# How to obtain mouse cursor coordinates during a file-drag operation in Explorer

Tags: c++, shell, winapi, drag-and-drop, explorer

When a user begins to drag a file in Explorer, mouse messages (and in particular, `WM_MOUSEMOVE`) are no longer sent to any Explorer windows, including the items-view child window. You can confirm this using Spy++.

So if you're subclassing the items-view child window, is there any other ideal way to obtain the mouse coordinates of the current drag operation? I don't see any shell object methods, and I don't think you can do it with UIAutomation, but perhaps I'm overlooking something. The only idea I have is to trap `WM_NCHITTEST`, which appears to keep getting sent (apparently on a timer) while the drag is active.

Comment: During a drag operation, the caller's message loop is blocked, the drag happens in a separate system modal loop, so it doesn't make sense for Windows to try to report mouse activity to the caller which it wouldn't be able to process. What are you trying to accomplish exactly? What do you expect to happen if the drag moves outside of the Explorer window you have subclassed? You could always use `GetCursorPos()` in a timer during the life of the drag, I suppose.

Comment: I'm experimenting with rolling my own drag-drop handler. I'm currently implementing an official drag-drop handler, but I don't like how it's limited to a small group of `DROPEFFECT` values.

Comment: During the drag and drop loop communication is via COM interfaces like `IDropSource` and `IDropTarget`, not window messages.